# instituting a button in tkinter that has multiple commands tied to it

Tags: python, tkinter

i cannot seem to get any of my buttons to create a new tab. i have a base that i like and believe looks good.
the first thing i want to implment is when the scan button is pressed a new tab opens up along with what it already does. I will attatch the code that i am using. it does not error out but any time i try to institue a new tab on button press it does not work

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('scan')

root['bg'] = 'black'

status = Label(root, text="now viewing : home", bd = 2, fg = "white", bg = "#3A3A3A", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = E)
status.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 0, sticky = W+E)


#introductory text
info = Label(root, text= "scan software", fg="white", bg="black")
info.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

#extra spaces get rid of over lap when selecting multiple choices
def Smart():
    label = Label(frame2, text="Smart Scan has been selected: Please wait   ", fg="white", bg="black", bd = 5)
    label.grid_forget()
    label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    status = Label(root, text="now viewing : Smart Scan", bd = 2, fg = "white", bg = "#3A3A3A", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = E)
    status.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 0, sticky = W+E)
    smart_scan.config(text = "Now Viewing", fg="black", bg="white", padx = 20, state = DISABLED)
    system_scan.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "System Scan", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 20)
    firenet.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "internet", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 40)
    cloud.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "Cloud", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 40)
    info.config(text = "info about smart scan", fg="white", bg="black")
    

def System():
    label = Label(frame2, text="System Scan has been selected: Please wait", fg="white", bg="black", bd = 5)
    label.grid_forget()
    label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    status = Label(root, text="now viewing : System Scan", bd = 2, fg = "white", bg = "#3A3A3A", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = E)
    status.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 0, sticky = W+E)
    smart_scan.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "Smart Scan", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 23.5)
    system_scan.config(text = "Now Viewing",fg="black", bg="white", padx = 20, state = DISABLED)
    firenet.config(state = ACTIVE,text = "internet", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 40)
    cloud.config(state = ACTIVE,text = "Cloud", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 40)
    info.config(text = "info about system scan", fg="white", bg="black")
    
def net():
    label = Label(frame2, text="internet has been selected: Please wait            ", fg="white", bg="black", bd = 5)
    label.grid_forget() 
    label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    status = Label(root, text="now viewing : internet", bd = 2, fg = "white", bg = "#3A3A3A", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = E)
    status.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 0, sticky = W+E)
    smart_scan.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "Smart Scan", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 25)
    system_scan.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "System Scan", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 20)
    net.config(text = "Now Viewing", fg="black", bg="white", padx = 23, state = DISABLED)
    cloud.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "Cloud", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 40)
    info.config(text = "info about internet")

def Cloud():
    label = Label(frame2, text="Cloud has been selected: Please wait             ", fg="white", bg="black", bd = 5)
    label.grid_forget()
    label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    status = Label(root, text="now viewing : Cloud", bd = 2, fg = "white", bg = "#3A3A3A", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = E)
    status.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 0, sticky = W+E)
    smart_scan.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "Smart Scan", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 25)
    system_scan.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "System Scan", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 20)
    firenet.config(state = ACTIVE, text = "internet", fg="white", bg="black", padx = 40)
    cloud.config(text = "Now Viewing", fg="black", bg="white", padx = 20, state = DISABLED)
    info.config(text = "info about cloud")

def Scan():
    label = Label(frame2, text = "Scanning has Started. Please Wait                ", fg="white", bg="black", bd = 5)
    label.grid_forget()
    label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5)
    status = Label(root, text="Scanning...", bd = 2, fg = "white", bg = "#3A3A3A", relief = SUNKEN, anchor = E)
    status.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady = 0, sticky = W+E)
    scan.config(text = "Scanning...", fg="black", bg="white", state = DISABLED)
    smart_scan.config(text = "Smart Scan", fg="white", bg="black", state = DISABLED)
    system_scan.config(text = "System Scan", fg="white", bg="black", state = DISABLED)
    firenet.config(text = "internet", fg="white", bg="black", state = DISABLED)
    cloud.config(text = "Cloud", fg="white", bg="black", state = DISABLED)
    info.config(text = "Scan in Progress")

#Framework
frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Redirect choices", padx = 5, pady = 5, fg="white", bg="black")
frame1.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root,text = "Choice made", fg="white", bg="black")
frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 3, pady = 5)

#Buttons
smart_scan = tk.Button(frame1, text="Smart Scan",padx=25, pady=35, command=Smart, fg="white", bg="black", bd = 10)
smart_scan.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 5)

system_scan = tk.Button(frame1, text="System Scan",padx=20, pady=35, command=System, fg="white", bg="black", bd = 10)
system_scan.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 10, pady = 5)

internet = tk.Button(frame1, text="internet",padx=40, pady=35, command=net, fg="white", bg="black", bd = 10)
internet.grid(row = 1, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 5)

cloud = tk.Button(frame1, text="Cloud",padx=40, pady=35, command=Cloud, fg="white", bg="black", bd = 10)
cloud.grid(row = 1, column = 5, padx = 10, pady = 5)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Close Software", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 20, padx = 10)

scan = tk.Button(root, text="Start Scan", padx =60, pady = 60, command = Scan, fg = "white", bg = "black", bd = 10)
scan.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 20, padx = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. Do we really need six buttons in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: You have not written code to add a new tab. Moreover, what is firenet? is it a label?